# TRUNCATE...CASCADE in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

This should be straightforward but I can't find it in the documentation or elsewhere. How can I `TRUNCATE...CASCADE` a table with foreign keys in Laravel 5.1 using the Eloquent ORM? Using just `User::truncate();` doesn't pass through the `CASCADE` argument.

Comment: Is a MySQL database?

Comment: No, I'm using Postgres - I'm looking to do this without writing raw SQL

Comment: I do not believe this is possible.  I see nothing in the API for this and the little research I've done, it looks like people are just using `DB::statement('TRUNCATE users CASCADE');`

Comment: @user3158900 I haven't found anything much either, which is annoying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this is by running the statement directly:

```
DB::statement('TRUNCATE users CASCADE');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `truncate` more than one table, you can remove the `CASCADE` keyword and provide a list of table names separated by comma.

```
    $tables = [
        'roles',
        'role_users',
        'users',
        'revisions',
    ];

    if (count($tables) > 1) {
        DB::statement('TRUNCATE TABLE ' . implode(',', $tables) . ';');
    } else {
        DB::statement('TRUNCATE TABLE ' . $tables[0] . ' CASCADE;');
    }
```